# Beginner C - Trying to terminate a loop when array is filled

Tags: c, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have a homework problem in which I have to record grades, put them in an array, and give the average. The program is supposed to ask for input until a negative number is given as a grade OR the array is filled. So far I am able to make the program loop until I give a negative number, and it calculates the correct average. What I can't figure out is how to terminate the loop when the array is filled. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function main begins program execution */
int main( void )
{  int counter; /* number of grade to be entered next */
   int grade; /* grade value */
   int total; /* sum of grades input by user */
   double average; /* average of grades */

   /* initialization phase */
   total = 0; /* initialize total */
   counter = 0; /* initialize counter */
   grade = 0;  /* initialize grade */

   printf( "Input a negative number when done entering grades.\n" );

   /* processing phase */
   #define MAX_GRADES 20
   int grades [MAX_GRADES];
   while ( counter < MAX_GRADES) {
     while ( grade >= 0 ) { /* loop until negative given */
       printf( "Enter grade: " ); /* prompt for input */
       scanf( "%d", &grade ); /* read grade from user */
       if (grade >= 0) {
     if (grade > 100)
       printf( "Grade is greater than 100. Please input grade again.\n" );
     else {
       grades[counter] = grade;
       total = total + grade; /* add grade to total */
       counter = counter + 1;
     } /* end else */
       } /* end if */
     } /* end while */
   } /* end while */

   /* termination phase */
    average = total /(double) counter; /* integer division */

   printf( "Class average is %f\n", average ); /* display result */
   return 0; /* indicate program ended successfully */
} /* end function main */
```

Comment: Instead of those horrible `/* end else */` etc. comments, you should perhaps indent your code in a way that makes sense. Then it will be obvious which bracket closes which one.

Comment: As a side note, kudos for saying "I have a homework problem".  Surprisingly many people posting homework problems don't say that.

Comment: Joe, when you post code here you should use 4 spaces instead of tabs. The indentation issues that @H2CO3 is talking about is due to your use of tabs.

Comment: Okay I'll keep that in mind. I pretty much copied the formatting from my homework, so I'll replace the tabs next time. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: IMHO it's not that tabs are evil per se, rather HTML can't handle them.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( counter < MAX_GRADES) {
    while ( grade >= 0 ) {
```

A loop within a loop will iterate x*y times. For each step of outer loop, the inner one will run from beginning to an end.

you need one loop checking both conditions:

```
while ( counter < MAX_GRADES && grade >= 0)
```

However, because you want to FIRST do things and THEN check for condition, the `do..while` loop suits here better. You can also `break` out of one loop at any time or `continue` to finish current run and move to next:

```
do{ /* loop */
   printf( "Enter grade: " ); /* prompt for input */
   scanf( "%d", &grade ); /* read grade from user */
   if (grade < 0)
     break;

   if (grade > 100){
     printf( "Grade is greater than 100. Please input grade again.\n" );
     continue;  
   }

   /* all abnormal conditions have been handled */
   /* now we're clear to do the actual job */

   grades[counter] = grade;
   total = total + grade; /* add grade to total */
   counter = counter + 1;

 }while ( counter < MAX_GRADES ) /*until array is full*/
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @JoeHill I've added `break` and `continue` which I believe are the point of your assignment.

Comment: My professor said that he didn't want us using break and continue for this assignment. I'm not sure why, but we'll probably use it at a later date.

Comment: that makes sense, not everything at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if

```
MAX_GRADES == counter
```

and break the loop. But this is done anyway...you don't have to change your code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get rid of the inner loop and just change the while condition on the outer loop to:

```
while ( counter < MAX_GRADES && grade >= 0 )
```